# Is there any possibility to make my chrome extension read and write directly from and to a local spreadsheet in my file system?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sheetjs

It seems that using file system API is not working any more with extensions, i have created a chrome extension that need to collect data from user interaction with the extension and send it to a spreadsheet in my local file system, and need to read data from the same spreadsheet when the user needs, my question now is not about code, it seems that most APIs not working any more to make extensions communicate with file system or at least what i have tried.

I have an alternative, to move everything to google sheets and make my extensions write and read from it but i wonder is there any way or API to make extensions able to read and write to local file system instantly without downloading the updated file every time user interact with the extension to make an update

Comment: Yes, use the *new* [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you you helped me so much, u are a life saver, if you want to add any answer so i can accept i would  be here